# Jquery remove table element

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery code that removes a table row. The problem is when I remove it, it forces my page to goto the top. 
The table row has a remove link that removes itself. I am assuming this is the issue that makes it scroll back to the top. I have tried setting the focus of another element outside to be focused after the removal but no joy. 
 I have now used the offset and scrolled to it, but it looks awful.
Anybody know how to stop the repositioning.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` to your event handler?

Comment: thank you very much, it was as simple of return false.

Comment: if you post it as an answer, I will ok it.

Comment: @YiJiang - make sure to post this as an answer, hopefully with some short example code :)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that the jquery code is actually running and deleting the row, but the html default functionality is also working.
try this to stop the links follow their href (i'm guessing you have href="#" which sends you by default to the top of the page)

```
   $('.remove').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault;
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
```